# How to add Db\NoRecordExists filter on run time with exclude condition in zf2..?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

How can one add **Db\NoRecordExists** input filter in **zf2** so it can validate posted data by matching the values in database excluding the entry we are editing..??

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists(
    array(
        'table' => 'users',
        'field' => 'username',
        'exclude' => array(
            'field' => 'id',
            'value' => $user_id
        )
    )
);
```

this doesn't work for me..!!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this problem. Basically the default NoRecordExists validator expects the value along with the column to be excluded in the configuration parameters. This can be changed in the controller as [mentioned by Ritesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23470725/540812); I played around for a while and got this solution.

I am using the context array variable which is available in isValid function. Instead of sending the id value, you send in the value of the form field to pick up from

in the InputFilter you have the following

```
$this->add ( array (
    'name'  => 'user_email',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array (
        array ( 
            'name' => 'StringTrim',
        ),
        array ( 
            'name' => 'StripTags',
        ),
    ),
    'validators' => array (
        array (
            'name' => 'EmailAddress',
            'options' => array (
                'domain' => true,
            )
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Application\Validator\NoRecordExists',
            'options' => array (
                'table' => 'user',
                'field' => 'user_email',
                'adapter' => \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter( ),
                'exclude' => array(
                    'field' => 'user_id',
                    'formValue' => 'user_id',
                ),
            )
        ),

    )
) );
```

Place an hidden element `user_id` in the form; the value set there is used whilst checking if the element is valid.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

class NoRecordExists extends \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists {

    public function isValid( $value, $context=array( ) ) {

        $exclude = $this->getExclude();

        if( is_array( $exclude ) ){
            if ( array_key_exists( 'formValue', $exclude ) ) {
                $formValue = $exclude[ 'formValue' ];
                $exclude[ 'value' ] = $context[ $formValue ];
                $this->setExclude( $exclude );
            }
        }

        return parent::isValid( $value );

    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen please try this in your controller and also remove the no record exist validation from model :

```
private function getUserTable()
{
    if (!$this->stateTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->userTable = $sm->get('Admin\Model\UserTable');
    }

return $this->userTable;
}
```

in edit action just add following lines--

```
$user = $this->getUserTable()->getUser($id);

$user->getInputFilter()->get('username')->getValidatorChain()->attach(new \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists(array('table' => 'users','field' => 'username','adapter' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'), 'exclude' => array('field' => 'id','value' => $id))));
```

where $id is your current user id on which you are performing edit..!! It works perfectly for me..!!

Comment: if I have a formFilter defined, how can I have all the validation in the filter instead of having it in the filter class, is there a way to do it